# why is assigning '\0' causes segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I've tried this code snippet to assign '\0' to the last character of a C string

```
char *words = "words";
words[4] = '\0';
```

why is line 2 causes segmentation fault?

Comment: The data `words` points to is *read-only*. When using pointers to literal strings, some programmers like to help themselves with `const`, as in `char const *words = "words";`

Comment: You're not supposed to modify a string literal.  Any attempt to do so leads to undefined behaviour.  One version of 'undefined behaviour' is that your code crashes because you attempt to modify read-only memory.  There are many other possible behaviours.  Don't do it.  It only leads to trouble.  If you must modify the string, make sure you have a modifiable array: `char words[] = "words";` — and now you can write `words[4] = '\0';` without danger.

Comment: @ChenDoytshman: String literals are intended to be immutable, and most platforms will store them in read-only memory (yours obviously does, which is why you got the segfault).  However, not all platforms do, and the behavior is on trying to modify a literal is left undefined by the language standard.  If you intend to modify the string, declare it as an *array* of `char` - `char words[N] = "words";`, where `N` is large enough to store whatever string you want to put there.  If you declare a pointer to a literal, best practice is to declare it `const` - `const char *words = "words";`.

Comment: @GenoChen: In what way is `char*` immutable?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't allocate the space for `"words"` (you only allocated the pointer to it), so (apparently) it has been placed some where you are not allowed to modify.

Comment: `"words"` itself (string literal) is an array of char. Depending on OP's objectives there may be no need to allocate any memory.

Comment: @pmg: My point was that since OP didn't allocate it, it was allocated for him, and thus is subject to whatever constraints were placed on it by that allocation.